# Add week in smarty tpl

Tags: date, smarty, smarty3

- Output: 2015-01-20 03:52:19
- Need    01.20.2015 + 1 week = 01.27.2015

I curently have `{$order[orders].invoice_date|date_format:"%d.%m.%Y"}`
But how to add week + 1?

So, I need to add 1 week and then formating this.
But the date isn't in the timestap format.

Smarty version: 3.1.
I can use only smarty logic, not PHP.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a plugin to work this out. It can be solved with a combination of [`cat`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.cat.tpl) and [`date_format`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.date.format.tpl).

Since [`date_format`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.date.format.tpl) is a wrapper to PHPs [`strftime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php), you can use the conversion specifiers available in [`strftime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) - and that is what I used tackle the issue at hand.

Try this:

```
{$order[orders].invoice_date|cat:' +1 week'|date_format:"%d.%m.%Y"}
```

I've used Smarty version `3.1.17` to recreate your problem. The solution is based on the assumption that the value in your variable `$order[orders].invoice_date` is a string `2015-01-20 03:52:19`.

Comment: That's a slick use of date_format :)  I still wouldn't recommend putting this kind of logic into the template, though :)

Comment: @AllanNienhuis I agree. It will almost always pay out in the long run to separate that kind of logic from the presentation layer of a smarty-driven project. But that wasn't the question! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a smarty plugin, something like this one to suit your needs. http://smarty.incutio.com/?page=AlternativeDateModifierPlugin

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be doing this logic in smarty at all. This type of thing should be done in the php code - assign two date values to two separate smarty variables (one with the 1 week added), and use the appropriate one in the appropriate place in your template (applying the appropriate date_format as required).

edit: I know you've said you want to do this using smarty syntax - I'm just pointing out that trying to do this type of manipulation in smarty is not what the template language is designed for.  If you only have access to the smarty .tpl files, you might try using the [{php}](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.php.tpl) tag to put your php logic in the .tpl file.